# How to parse strings with c# in Windows 8?

Tags: c#, html, windows-8, windows-store-apps, winrt-xaml

I've a web page with this part of HTML code:

```
<meta property="og:type" content="photo" />
    <meta property="og:description" content="descrizione">

    <meta property="og:site_name" content="Site_Name" />
    <meta property="og:title" content="" />
    <meta property="og:image" content="http://addfsfdbyhdfsifd.jpg" />
    <meta property="og:determiner" content="a" />
    <meta property="fb:app_id" content="124024574287414" />
    <meta property="og:url" content="http://addfsfdbyhdfsifd.com" />
```

How can I pick the content of the property="og:image"? I need to get that link to show it in my app.

Comment: You want to parse it using C#? On the server-side?

Comment: Take a look at at the Html Agility pack for parsing Html in C# http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/

Comment: Should be a comment...

Comment: Even closed, it is polite to mark the best answer.

Answer (score 3):

Using [HtmlAgilityPack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/)

```
HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
doc.LoadHtml(html);

var props = doc.DocumentNode.Descendants("meta")
            .ToDictionary( m => m.Attributes["property"].Value,
                            m => m.Attributes["content"].Value);

Console.WriteLine(props["og:image"]);
```

Comment: If there's any two meta tags with the same property, this code will bomb.

Comment: @Shlomo Yes, an html page containing multiple meta tags with the same property name deserves this.

Comment: The page deserves it, and the developer of the page does as well. But the developer of the parser may not.

Comment: @Shlomo Then OP can simply replace `ToDictionary` with `ToLookup` :)

Answer (score 1):

Here's the no-fail way to do it.

1. I am not a fan of third party libraries to solve a little problem. No offense to the agility pack, by the way. It's super great and powerful. You never want to parse HTML on your own. But this is such a little edge case! Why screw with it?
2. You can't be sure the HTML will parse, so you need something else. XML is tempting but unless you are 100% positive this is valid XHTML (which nothing really is anymore) it's better to not do chase it. Just treat this as a string parsing exercise.

And what parses strings best? [Regular Expressions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az24scfc.aspx), that's what.

Here's your solution:

```
var s = @"
<meta property=""og:type"" content=""photo"" />
<meta property=""og:description"" content=""descrizione"">
<meta property=""og:site_name"" content=""Site_Name"" />
<meta property=""og:title"" content="""" />
<meta property=""og:image"" content=""http://addfsfdbyhdfsifd.jpg"" />
<meta property=""og:determiner"" content=""a"" />
<meta property=""fb:app_id"" content=""124024574287414"" />
<meta property=""og:url"" content=""http://addfsfdbyhdfsifd.com"" />";

// first define what you will look for using regex pattern syntax
var p = @"meta\s{1,}property=""og:image""\s{1,}content=""(.+)""\s{0,}/>";

// second let the regex engine use your pattern against your html string
var m = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Match(s, p);

// third pull out just the part you want from the resulting match
var g = m.Groups[1];

// forth get the value from the meta tag, specifically the og:image you wanted
var i = g.Value;
```

Yep, it's that easy. And Regex makes it more reliable, too.

Best of luck!

Answer (score 0):

Code to set up HtmlDocument:

```
var s = @"
<meta property=""og:type"" content=""photo"" />
<meta property=""og:description"" content=""descrizione"">

<meta property=""og:site_name"" content=""Site_Name"" />
<meta property=""og:title"" content="""" />
<meta property=""og:image"" content=""http://addfsfdbyhdfsifd.jpg"" />
<meta property=""og:determiner"" content=""a"" />
<meta property=""fb:app_id"" content=""124024574287414"" />
<meta property=""og:url"" content=""http://addfsfdbyhdfsifd.com"" />";

HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlDocument();
doc.LoadHtml(s);
```

Find the node, get the attribute.

```
var node = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//meta[@property='og:image']").FirstOrDefault();

var content = node != null
    ? node.GetAttributeValue("content", string.Empty)
    : string.Empty;
```

Comment: XPath? WHAT? Why are you still using XPath?

Comment: It works, yes. Is it readable? No. Is there better ways to do it? Yes.

Comment: Feel free to provide a better, more readable answer.

Comment: I disagree; I dig xPath. Elegant and powerful. If you know it you can read it. If you don't know it, of course it's difficult. Duh. Lambdas, Regex, F# - what you don't know is always challenging.That argument is silliness. Having said that, most HTML documents won't parse into an XmlDocument.